# Jquery plugin CrossSlide implementation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a site that is supposed to use the crossSlide jquery plugin, but it does not work. I have been breaking my teeth trying to figure it out. Does anyone know why the following does not work?

```
<script src='script/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="script/jquery.cross-slide.min.js" TYPE="text/JavaScript"></SCRIPT>
<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#splash').crossSlide({
        sleep: 2,
        fade: 1
    }, [
        { src: 'images/hpmain2.JPG' },
        { src: 'images/hpmain1.jpg' }
    ]);
});
</script>
```

There is a div with the id splash.

Thanks

Comment: Your code looks valid, though i can't visit your url to do further testing. I suspect the error is elsewhere than the js/html you've provided.

Comment: Do you find why that not working?

Comment: No, I ended up using a different script. It was easier...

Comment: @Meir can you please suggest another plugin / script? I am having same trouble as you had. Thank you

Comment: I do not remember any more what project this was one, I did it so long ago. I am sorry for that